# Can not access dashboard of kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration

When i execute

> kubectl proxy

it gives me o/p: Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001 on virtual machine

i want to see dashboard on host machine it gives me problem.

> 192 168 113 8001 api namespaces kube system services https kubernetes dashboard proxy

What is problem, i didn't get it. I am new to kubernetes.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use kubectl proxy, you should then access the dashboard with the URL http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ from the machine where you ran the kubectl proxy command.

From
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/
 :

> You can access Dashboard using the kubectl command-line tool by
>   running the following command:
>
> ```
> kubectl proxy
> ```
>
> Kubectl will handle authentication with apiserver and make Dashboard
>   available at
>   http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.
>
> The UI can only be accessed from the machine where the command is
>   executed. See kubectl proxy --help for more options.

Comment: Thanks  it gives me issue on my local host 
192 168 113 8001 api namespaces kube system services https kubernetes dashboard proxy